# Error while executing ionic cordova emulate android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've created a new ionic application

```
ionic start test blank
```

Without making any changes, I try to run the Android emulador

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

Console outputs

```
Running app-scripts build: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-
ort 35729 --r 35729 --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[12:21:29]  build dev started ...
[12:21:29]  clean started ...
[12:21:29]  clean finished in 4 ms
[12:21:29]  copy started ...
[12:21:29]  transpile started ...
[12:21:31]  transpile finished in 2.53 s
[12:21:32]  preprocess started ...
[12:21:32]  deeplinks started ...
[12:21:32]  deeplinks finished in 9 ms
[12:21:32]  preprocess finished in 10 ms
[12:21:32]  webpack started ...
[12:21:32]  copy finished in 2.72 s
[12:21:40]  webpack finished in 8.93 s
[12:21:40]  sass started ...
[12:21:41]  sass finished in 877 ms
[12:21:41]  postprocess started ...
[12:21:41]  postprocess finished in 11 ms
[12:21:41]  lint started ...
[12:21:41]  build dev finished in 12.40 s
> cordova emulate android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Desarrollo\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova emulate android (exit code 1).
```

Any idea on what's happenning? Same error ocurrs with another ionic application(this new blank one is a test to check the problem was not caused by myself).
Same error happens when running `ionic cordova run android`

- ionic 3.1.2
- cordova 7.0.1
- npm 3.10.9

UPDATE: added `ionic info` output

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.1.2
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.1.2

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.1.2
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.1.2
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1

System:

    Node       : v7.1.0
    OS         : Windows 8.1
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

`ionic info` warned me there were some updates, which ended up in new configuration:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1

System:

    Node       : v7.1.0
    OS         : Windows 8.1
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
```

Error persists after updating.

Tried `ionic cordova run android --livereload` but the result's the same.

Comment: can you output `ionic info` ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the output.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

ionic cordova run android --livereload

Comment: Thanks, will try later

Comment: Download an external emulator like Genymotion thats the best work around for now

Comment: Made the change to a linux computer and everything worked from the start. Thanks for the input!